# Kubernetes error - context deadline exceeded

Tags: python-3.x

I am facing the below error in Kubernetes which is in external-dns.

"time="2022-03-09T10:30:20Z" level=fatal msg="failed to sync *v1.Ingress: context deadline exceeded"

Help me in fixing this error.

Regards
lakshmi

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

There are some possible answers for this problem listed here:

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/2599

For me, I had a problem with the namespace on the cluster-role-bindings.yaml

```
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: external-dns-viewer
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: external-dns
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: external-dns
  namespace: ingress-management
```

It must be the same namespace where you are deploying your external-dns

Comment: Seems like the correct answear to me.